# Finite geometric series of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometric-series

Suppose $A$ is a $m \times m$ matrix. Under what condition(s) does the following finite geometric series hold? Note that $I$ is a $m \times m$ identity matrix.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n A(I - A)^i = I - (I - A)^{n+1}$$

I'm referring to [https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh96.pdf](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emath211/m211oh/m211oh96.pdf), and it seems that the above would hold if $(I - A)$ is invertible, i.e. $|\lambda_i| < 1$ for each eigenvalue of $A$? Does that imply that $A$ also has to be invertible?

Comment: I'm guessing the left side should read $\sum_{i = 0}^n (I - A)^i$?

Comment: "if $(I - A)$ is invertible, **i.e.** $|\lambda_i| < 1$ for each eigenvalue of $A$" really? For $A=\operatorname{diag}(3,5)$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=3,\,\lambda_2=5$ $\quad I-A=\operatorname{diag}(-2,-4)$ is invertible and $(I-A)^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(-\frac12,-\frac14)$... Btw, recall how the usual geometric progression sum is derived, like $qS_n=S_n+bq^n-b$, the same argument applies here if $Q=(I-A)$...

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I see, thanks. For the equality to hold, do we only need $A$ to be invertible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n Q^k$ where $Q=(I-A)$. Then
$$QS_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} Q^k=-I+S_n+Q^{n+1}$$
Bring $S_n$ to the left part:
$$(Q-I)S_n=-I+Q^{n+1}$$
now recalling $Q=I-A$ and multiplying by $(-1)$ we get the desired result.

P.S. No assumptions taken.

Comment: Thank you. On a related note, if we take $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n BQ^k,$ where $Q = (I-A)$, then we would have $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n BQ^k = BA^{-1}(I-(I-A)^{n+1})$? In this case, we would need to assume that $A$ is invertible, correct?

Comment: I hope so, if we write $A^{-1}$. For non-invertable $A$ it doesn't make sense otherwise) Alternatively we may leave $A$ in the LHS, as done in the question. However, I'm not sure whether it's OK that $A^{-1}$ is between $B$ and $(I-(I-A)^{n+1})$. How did it get there?)

Comment: Hmm, I thought since $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n BQ^k = B\sum_{k=0}^n Q^k = BA^{-1}(I-(I-A)^{n+1})$, then the $A^{-1}$ is between $B$ and $(I - (I-A)^{n+1})$? Is it incorrect that I pulled out $B$ in front of the sum in the second equality?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n BQ^k=B\sum\limits_{k=0}^n Q^k$ is perfectly correct, it's distributivity. Another thing that now we maybe should write $S_nQ=-B+S_n+BQ^{n+1}$ and thus $S_n(-A)=B(-I+Q^{n+1})$. Anyway, $A^{-1}$ (if exists) and $(I-(I-A^{n+1}))$ appears to commute, so that's fine having $A^{-1}$ in between (after some thinking). Thanks for reading)